# How to get the Value from column in below shown Visualforce Pageblock Table to apex method?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, visualforce-component, inline-visualforce

[image: Visualforce page with results]

> i want to take the value in Unit column and pass it to a variable in apex method as parameter.
>   below is the Vf page code and apex method`

```
 <apex:pageblockTable value="{!Cond}" var="a" id="table">
  <apex:column headerValue="Select" width="50px">
  <apex:commandLink action="{!addtoLead}" value="Select" rendered="true"/>
  <apex:param name="UnitNameParam" value="{!a.name}" assignTo="      {!Unitnamevf}"/>
     </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Unit Name" id="unitname" value="{!a.Name}"   width="50px"/>
     <apex:column headerValue="Beds" value="{!a.Beds__c}" width="50px"/>
     <apex:column headerValue="Square Footage" value="{!a.Square_Footage__c}" width="80px"/>
     <apex:column headerValue="Initial List Price" value="{!a.Initial_List_Price__c}" width="80px"/> 
     <apex:column headerValue="Status" value="{!a.Status__c}" width="80px"/>
   </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>`
```

> Below is the apex Method`

```
   Public Pagereference addtolead() {

  Unitnamevf = 
  LeadRecordId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');

    List<Lead> Lds = new List<Lead>([select Id from Lead where Id=   :LeadRecordId]);
    if(!Lds.isEmpty()) 
    {
      Lds[0].Condo_Unit__c = 'Unitnamevf'; 
      update Lds[0];
        }

   return null;
  }`
```

> I want to take value from UnitName in Pageblock table and pass it to    "Unitnamevf" variable in apex method.kindly help me

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to refresh the standard Lead page from Inline visualforce Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with Shankar's suggestions,

To use the apex:param with apex:commandLink, you will have to enclose the apex:param within the commandLink tag like below :

```
 <apex:commandLink action="{!addtoLead}" value="Select" rendered="true" reRender="formid">
      <apex:param name="UnitNameParam" value="{!a.name}"/>
 </apex:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the 'assignTo' attr from visualforce part and in controller you can directly use

Unitnamevf = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('UnitNameParam');

Comment: @shanksr, i am getting below error when trying to save the code.Error: Condosearchcontroller Compile Error: line 109:65 no viable alternative at character '"' at line 109 column 65

Comment: I have replaced your line with Unitnamevf = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('UnitNameParam'); using single quotes.now ia m not getting any error but value is not getting passed to Unitnamevf.

Comment: yes, I have changed the answer to replace double cote with single cote. @Chaitanya can you try Swati's suggestion also. I think that might be the problem.